# Google GO: routing request handling mystical declarations?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm dorking around with Google GO for the first time.  I've extended the "hello world" application to try to have paths defined in the init section.  Here's what I've done so far:

```
package hello

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/service", serviceHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/site", siteHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, there")
}

func serviceHandler( w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "this is Services")
}

func siteHandler( w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "this is Sites")
}
```

Only the `handler()` callback is ever executed -- the others are ignored.  E.g.: `http://myserver/service/foo` prints `Hello, there`.  I had hoped that it would be `this is Services`.

Is there a better way to do service routing?  Ideally, I would expect these to be separate scripts anyway, but it looks like Go has only one script, based on the fact that the app.yaml requires a special string `_go_app` in the script declaration.

Thanks!

Comment: Go doesn't have scripts. It's a compiled language.

Comment: Technically, all languages are compiled.  But, we digress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation at: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux

path specs that do not have a trailing slash only match that path exactly. Add a slash to the end like so: `http.HandleFunc("/service/", serviceHandler)` and it will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks. I was just following the hello world on the google developer site, and it doesn't mention ServiceMux, so I appreciate the reference.